# Working with db_like drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Can somebody show me an example how should I use the drupal 7 db_like function with a simple query?

Comment: Did you look at the function documentation? What exactly didn't you understand from the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = db_select('person', 'p')
  ->fields('p')
  ->condition('name', db_like($prefix) . '%', 'LIKE')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
```

Taken from [this page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_like/7).